# Is it possible to turn a float value into a datetime value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a `Year` column in my database that holds years as `float` values e.g. (2014,2013,2012).

Is it possible to convert these into a `DateTime`? The day, month and time values don't matter I just need them in a `DateTime` type for another application.

e.g. Can I convert the `float` 2014 into a `DateTime` value of `2014-01-01 00:00:00.000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just convert to a string and cast to a datetime:

```
select cast(cast(year as varchar(255)) + '0101' as datetime)
```

Comment: You have an excess `)` after `'0101'`.

Comment: Worked Perfectly, thanks for the help. Now I can finally move on :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can! However, you need to use `FLOOR` or `CEILING` and then cast the `FLOAT` column to `INT`.

```
DECLARE @year FLOAT = 2014

SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, CAST(FLOOR(@year) AS INT) - 1900, 0)
```

---

Or you can just directly `CAST` your `FLOAT` column to `INT`:

```
DECLARE @year FLOAT = 2014.1

SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, CAST(@year AS INT) - 1900, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE DATE_DATA(Date_Values FLOAT)
GO

INSERT INTO DATE_DATA VALUES (2012),(2013),(2014)
GO

-- Add a new column to your table 
ALTER TABLE DATE_DATA 
ADD New_Date_Value DATETIME;
GO

-- use an update statement to populate the new column
UPDATE DATE_DATA
 SET New_Date_Value = CAST(CAST(Date_Values AS VARCHAR(4)) + '0101' AS DATETIME)
GO

-- get rid of the old float column
ALTER TABLE DATE_DATA
DROP COLUMN Date_Values;
GO

-- finally rename the new column to old column name
sp_RENAME 'DATE_DATA.[New_Date_Value]' , 'Date_Values', 'COLUMN'
GO
```